# unity-greeter login background won't change according to the user that is highlighted

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Recently, I change to use another Accounts Service which could remove certain users from the graphic login screen of unity-greeter. I downloaded source code from a branch of

https://github.com/mmonaco/accountsservice.git

which is named exclude-v3.
After compiling and installation, things seem to work.
However, I found that the background of unity-greeter is always that purple one, not my wallpaper as before. And when changing the highlight user name to login, the background won't change at all.

I have tried all of the following methods, but none of them seems to work.

1) Change my wallpaper and then change back to the original one, or

2) "gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds true"

or do that under the name of user lightdm

I also checked " /var/lib/AccountsService/users/myusername " to ensure the setting there is correct.
I checked the permission of the wallpaper file, which is " -rw-r--r--" and belongs to me.

So is there anyone who can give me some advice on what next I could try, or should I directly contact with the one who works on that new branch? ( Actually it seems not that new according to the last commit date )

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would have thought you need to uninstall the package that broke it?

Comment: Actually, I didn't uninstall the old accountsservice package from apt-get. By using 'sudo make install' in the folder that contains source code, I think the new one just cover the old one. So, you mean that may cause problems?

Comment: Well that might help, but if the problem started when you installed a new package, then the package is probably the problem. Try uninstalling it, or contacting the developer or even editing the code yourself.

Comment: In fact, I didn't install any new package use dpkg or apt-get. Building from source code and installing it using 'make install' won't cause any changes to the package management system, I think. For apt-get, it is still thinking I'm using the old version. Maybe I should use the source code to build a package first and then use 'dpkg -i' to install it. Well, long way to go.